# How to allow accessing the AWS Buckets and folders from specific IP ranges

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

We have data in S3 storage area, is there a way we can create a IAM group policy that allows the user to access the S3 from specific IP range only.

If we give like 111.111.111.23/24 it will allow all IP's from 111.111.111.0 to 111.111.111.255 range, but if I want to allow access only from 111.111.111.23 to 111.111.111.60, is there a way?

One way is I can add all the ips with in that list. But is there any other way we can specify the range.

Can any one help me on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what AWS documentation says about [Restricting Access to Specific IP Addresses](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-bucket-policies.html#example-bucket-policies-use-case-3):

> Also note that the `aws:sourceIp` values use the CIDR notation described in RFC 2632

CIDR, or Classless Inter-Domain Routing, always denotes IP ranges starting from `x.x.x.0`. Depending on the given [prefix size](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classless_Inter-Domain_Routing#CIDR_notation), your range will be big or small (the bigger the prefix size, the smaller the range).

**But the range can never start at something like `111.111.111.23`.**

Thus, you cannot use CIDR notation to specify an arbitrary IP range for your case. That means you have to specify the whole list of addresses.

Comment: I got your point, what I mean to say is If I want give the access only for some range in the range of 0 to 255, is it possible. If we give x.x.x.0/24, it will allow accessing from 0 to 255, but what we want is ip range from x.x.x.23 to x.x.x.60 should have the access for aws.

Comment: @GHK I understand, you stated that in the question. No, it's not possible to restrict the range. You can allow 0..255, but not 23..60 (not using CIDR notation, that is). You'll have to pass the whole list.

Comment: @awendt, x.x.x.0 is not correct.  CIDR notation is more flexible, e.g., 192.168.1.4/30 matches .4, .5, .6 .7... so it's possible to specify any arbitrary range using *some number* of CIDR blocks, though not always a single CIDR block.